# Find the observations with the largest values that make up a specific percentage of the total

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, panel-data

I observe many customers (or "users") and their visit times on many days. Now I want to select the customers that make up 80% of the total visit time across customers. To be more precise, I want to successively select the customers with the highest overall visit times until the cut-off of 80% of cumulative visit time across customers is reached.

Example Data:

```
da = data.frame(userid = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), day = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2), total_visit_time = c(28,4,312,22,1,93,30,67,211,81))
da
   userid day total_visit_time
1       1   1               28
2       1   2                4
3       2   1              312
4       2   2               22
5       3   1                1
6       3   2               93
7       4   1               30
8       4   2               67
9       5   1              211
10      5   2               81
```

I have figured out how it works if I only have one observation per customer with the total visit time across days, but I want to keep the data structure of my example data.

Example Data: Let’s say, we observe 10 users and their total visit times in seconds:

```
da = data.frame(userid = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), total_visit_time = c(28,4,312,22,1,93,30,67,211,81))
da
   userid total_visit_time
1       1               28
2       2                4
3       3              312
4       4               22
5       5                1
6       6               93
7       7               30
8       8               67
9       9              211
10     10               81
```

We compute the overall visit time across customers, which is 849 seconds. We order the customers in descending order based on their visit time:

```
da = da %>% mutate(overall_time = sum(total_visit_time)) %>%
   arrange(desc(total_visit_time))
da
   userid total_visit_time overall_time
1       3              312          849
2       9              211          849
3       6               93          849
4      10               81          849
5       8               67          849
6       7               30          849
7       1               28          849
8       4               22          849
9       2                4          849
10      5                1          849
```

We compute the cumulative time spent across customers (based on the descending order):

```
da = da %>%
   mutate(cumulative_time = cumsum(total_visit_time))
da
   userid total_visit_time overall_time cumulative_time
1       3              312          849             312
2       9              211          849             523
3       6               93          849             616
4      10               81          849             697
5       8               67          849             764
6       7               30          849             794
7       1               28          849             822
8       4               22          849             844
9       2                4          849             848
10      5                1          849             849
```

We compute the cumulative percentage of visit time on the overall time across customers:

```
da = da %>% mutate(percentage_of_time = cumulative_time/overall_time)
da         
   userid total_visit_time overall_time cumulative_time percentage_of_time
1       3              312          849             312              0.367
2       9              211          849             523              0.616
3       6               93          849             616              0.726
4      10               81          849             697              0.821
5       8               67          849             764              0.900
6       7               30          849             794              0.935
7       1               28          849             822              0.968
8       4               22          849             844              0.994
9       2                4          849             848              0.999
10      5                1          849             849              1.000
```

We filter out customers with < .80 cumulative percentage of visit time:

```
da = filter(da, percentage_of_time < .80)
da
  userid total_visit_time overall_time cumulative_time percentage_of_time
1      3              312          849             312              0.367
2      9              211          849             523              0.616
3      6               93          849             616              0.726
```

How does it work for my grouped data, if I want to keep all observations of a customer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
da = data.table(userid = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5), 
                day = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2), 
                total_visit_time = c(28,4,312,22,1,93,30,67,211,81))
da[,perc_visit := sum(total_visit_time)/sum(da$total_visit_time), by = userid]
da_unique <- unique(da[,.(userid,perc_visit)])[order(-perc_visit),][,cum_perc_visit := cumsum(perc_visit)]
da <- merge(da,da_unique[,.(userid,cum_perc_visit)], by = "userid")[order(cum_perc_visit)]
da[cum_perc_visit<0.8,]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! I usually prefer dplyr, but I will use this for my code.